# OrderBy fixed to asc on Eloquent query

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I try to convert the following SQL request in an Eloquent query :

```
SELECT  locals.*
FROM prises JOIN locals
  ON prises.liaison_id = locals.id
GROUP BY locals.id
ORDER BY COUNT(liaison_id);
```

And I wrote this :

```
return $query->select('locals.*')
                ->from('prises')
                ->join('locals', function($join) {
                    $join->on('prises.liaison_id', '=', 'locals.id');
                })
                ->orderBy(DB::raw('count(prises.liaison_id)', 'DESC'))
                ->groupBy('locals.id');
```

On my php page, it works, but this query is running :

```
select "locals".* from "prises" 
inner join "locals" on "prises"."liaison_id" = "locals"."id" 
group by "locals"."id" 
order by count(prises.liaison_id) asc limit 100 offset 0
```

My Asc/Desc is fixed, and I don't know why. Is using DB::raw that block me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: , 'DESC' should be outside of DB::raw statement. orderBy(DB::raw('count(prises.liaison_id)'), 'desc')

Comment: ->orderByRaw('count(prises.liaison_id) desc')